# TToast двигает другие компоненты

Tags: android, delphi, button, firemonkey

Разрабатываю на **Android** используя Delphi Firemonkey.
[image: Форма]

У формы в принципе лишь один компонент визуальный, который всегда на экране - кнопка.
По нажатию на нее используется компонент TToast - [инфа](https://www.cybertribe.de/info/components/fmx/toast/)

Проблема в том, что когда сообщение "toast" появляется внизу (align - Bottom), то оно двигает кнопку вверх (align - center), а кнопка после пропадания сообщения назад не возвращается.
Пробовал менять Align-ы, свойства TToast, кнопки - результат тот же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что сам Toast создается невидимым (`FLayout.Visible:=False`), а после показа - просто становится прозрачным, не удаляясь с экрана. С учетом того, что для компонента возможно задать выравнивание - это в корне некорректное поведение для быстрого уведомления, пользоваться таким компонентом не стоит. Появление уведомления не должно затрагивать уже существующие на форме контролы, тем более - менять положение выровненных (Align<>None).

Если вы работаете с android - пользуйтесь модулем `Android.JNI.Toast.pas` из того же архива и его процедурой `Toast` (не проверял работоспособность). Если необходимы и другие платформы - ищите альтернативы, например - [FGX](http://fire-monkey.ru/forum/188-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-download-versions/)

Еще один вариант - написать автору этого компонента или поправить код самому.

Comment: Спасибо, пришлось каплю подправить Android.JNI.Toast.pas, чтобы получить желаемый результат, тем не менее, теперь все компоненты вверх не сдвигаются. Да и как я понял, "тост" отображается везде, какая программа не была бы открыта.